# Adding the Target attribute for a DIV tag

Tags: html

I would like to add a target attribute to a div tag (see code below) so that the page "index.html" opens in the same page i.e target_self

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I'm trying to add the target attribute to

```
<div id="home" style="cursor:pointer;"href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('index.html')"></div>
```